# Evaluating PostFix Function

Tags: c++, stack, postfix-notation

Below I am trying to write a program that evaluates postfix expressions. However, I noticed that the two elements that I am setting to be operated on are not being set to the correct values. I am still learning the stack feature in the c++ library, so if anyone could explain why this is happening, I would greatly appreciate it!

```
/*Sample output:
Enter an infix or prefix expression:3+4-1
Postfix is: 34+1-
postFix[i]: 3
postFix[i]: 4
element1: 52
element2: 51
val is: 103
postFix[i]: 1
element1: 49
element2: 103
val is: 54
Value is 54*/

int evaluatePostfix (string postFix)
{
     stack<int> operands;

        int length = postFix.length();
        int val = 0;
        for ( int i = 0; i < length; i++ )
        {
                //if the char is a digit push the digit onto the stack
                if( isdigit( postFix[i] ))
                {
                        operands.push( postFix[i] );
                        cout << "postFix[i]: " << postFix[i] << endl;
                }
                else if ( isOperator(postFix[i]) )
                {
                        //
                        //element 1 and element 2 will be the element on the top of the stack
                        //
                        int element1 = operands.top();
                        cout << "element1: " << element1 << endl;
                        operands.pop();
                        int element2 = operands.top();
                        cout << "element2: " << element2 << endl;
                        operands.pop();
                        //
                        //create a switch statement that evaluates the elements based on the operator
                        //
                        switch( postFix[i] )
                        {
                                case '+':
                                        val = element2 + element1;
                                        cout << "val is: " << val << endl;
                                        operands.push(val);
                                        break;
                                case '-':
                                        val = element2 - element1;
                                        cout << "val is: " << val << endl;
                                        operands.push(val);
                                        break;
                                case '*':
                                        val = element2 * element1;
                                        operands.push(val);
                                        break;
                                case '/':
                                        val = element2 / element1;
                                        operands.push(val);
                                        break;
                                default:
                                        return 0;
                        }

                                                                                 }

        }
        return val;
}
```

Comment: Can you give a solid example? For instance, I push 3 but it pops 42.

Comment: I think that's the problem here. I am pushing these elements on the stack, but the elements that I am pushing onto the stack are not the elements that are being popped off. So, for example, I push 3 and 4. Then, the program sees the operator '+' and decides to pop off the top two elements, which should be 3 and 4, but it's popping off random numbers like 52 and 51. I am not sure why it's doing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your postfix is a string and when you push those characters (which are valid integers) you get the [ascii](http://ascii.cl/) value back (e.g. 51, 52). Those correspond to the correct numbers (e.g. 3, 4)

What you end up with is a value that is offset by 48 which corresponds to the 0 symbol.

Comment: I am still learning about ascii values and I haven't completely understood how they work just yet. How do I accommodate for this?

Comment: A simple solution, since you know the offset if 48, is subtract 48 from what's being returned from the stack or before you push it..51 - 48 = 3 and 52 - 48 = 4, and so on. @ChynnaHernandez

Comment: Thank you for your explanations

Comment: Glad to help @ChynnaHernandez!